# Partition used and available size in bytes

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm not a linux pro, and maybe I have overlooked something in the docs, but:

`df -ah`, for instance, returns automatically largest unit: `M` / `G` / `T`.

simply `df` with no options, returns, what I assume are sectors not bytes.

`parted /dev/sda1 unit B print`

It displays in bytes, but it does not return the `used` / `available` bytes.

I have heard about converting sectors to actual sizes, but I have no idea how would I do that.

How could I return the actual bytes of partition?

Comment: Try this command: `df -B1`

Comment: It's closer, but the result differs: `parted /dev/sdd1 unit B print` == `3221225472B` == `3221225472`, where `df -B1 -a | grep /dev/sdd1` for `Used` + `Available` == `1152532480` + `1857056768` = `3009589248`. And `3221225472` - `3009589248` = `211636224`. In that case, where have those 201MiB's went?

Comment: The space allocatable by a file system is not equal to the size of the underlying partition. `df` reports file system sizes, `parted` reports partition sizes. The difference is caused by file system overhead.

Comment: Oh, and these 201MiB's are OK for filesystem on 3.0GiB partition?

Comment: No, I guess this is too much. But I don't know your setup, e.g. if your file system is using the maximum available size of your partition. So what is it that you actually want?

Comment: I simply want to retrieve the actual size in bytes, I'm developing an web application that needs these values. That `sdd1` partition resides in a USB flash. Partition is 3GB, and the filesystem there is built with `mkfs.ext4`, the particular partition is bootable (contains OS).

Comment: The actual size of what? Available file system space? Used file system space? Partition size? For partition size just use your `parted /dev/sdd1 unit B print` command, otherwise use `df -B1` and don't sum up the used + available space but use the given total numbers instead.

Comment: Total file system space. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4675/discussion-between-psycketom-and-speakr)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need the partition size, you should be fine with the command you already mentioned:

```
parted /dev/sdd1 unit B print
```

If you need the total file system size, you can use the total numbers given by `df`:

```
df -B1 /dev/sdd1
```

Note that if you sum up used and available space given by `df`, it will be less than the given total space. This is due to file system overhead, e.g. the journal.

If you want to modify or just have a look on your file system setup consider the `tune2fs` and `dumpe2fs` manpages.

Comment: For Cygwin use `D:/` or with backslash to see other drive than Cygwin resides on.